# book class recommendation

Tags: books

I 'm writing a book with many environments (*theorems*, *propositions*, *nota bene*, *dialogs*, *function plots*, *examples* etc) with `tikz`, `tcolorbox`, `dialogue` and `pgfplot` like the picture below.

[image]

I use `include` and `includeonly`, but I don't know if I have more to do. For example, should I externalize the pictures of the plots?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: it isn't clear what kind of answer you want, none of the things that you mention have much impact on the choice of class, since you can use the same packages such as `tikz` with any of them.  Start with one of the usual choices `book`, `memoir` or `scrbook` unless you find a custom class that adds some feature that you particularly like or need.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought that the the compiling speed might depends of  how I construct the file. Also I thought that the memory has limits. I don't know if is something else that I couldn't imagine, so I asked for advises.

Comment: I don't think that there is any answer in this generality, nothing you mention affects the choice of document class. tikz for example is a big package and takes a while to load, and large tikz diagrams can stress the tex memory allocations, but that is true whatever document class you use.